# Cannot animate grid from previous value to a new value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to animate the grid height property from two variables, the previous height and the new height. The problem I am facing is that I repeatedly load a new set of values and in turn reload the data binding. When the XAML binding gets loaded, all previous values are lost and we just have the new variable.

I realise I can just store the value in the model however I want to do this just in XAML code and have no dependency on the old values.

This is what I have so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="MeasureGrid"  Background="{Binding bindingBackgroundColor}" MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Loaded="startAnimaton" >
<Grid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" Completed="completed">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MeasureGrid"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            From="30"
            To="{Binding bindingNewHeight}" 
            Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Grid.Resources>
```

As you can see, it is the "From" property that is the issue. Can anyone point out a way to tackle this?

Comment: Just don't set it. It will then animate from the current value.

Comment: I have tried this, however the current value is 0 because I reload the data binding repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

you can always try to bind the from value to the height of the measuregrid like so:

```
 From="{Binding ElementName=MeasureGrid, Path=Height}"
```

Else you could remove the `From` and `To` attributes and use the `By` attribute

Comment: but we are reloading the binding every time so essentially the Height property is 0 each time it gets called.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a ListView, and each ListItem has a Grid inside. When my server pushes a new set of data, I need to reassign the new List<Object> to the DataSource, and the data binding reloads the list. the grid inside should change height from the previous to the new. how can I do this if my array of objects is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the FillBehavior of the Storyboard and removing the From attribute?

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" Completed="completed">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="MeasureGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
        EnableDependentAnimation="True"            
        To="{Binding bindingNewHeight}"
        FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
        Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

This is what I would try.